# Identification story: Features a father & son, body modification

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, spaceship, technology

I am looking for a short story about a father and son (the mother is out of the picture) who are of a religion that doesn't believe in body modification or enhancement.

It is set in the future when that is a common practice, and they are on a spaceship (or some such place) where the only work available to the boy is by accepting the body modifications in order to work on something in an extreme environment. He does and the complications follow.

The story also has some super all-answers computer/instructor, like the Internet with a personality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [Inclination](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3149915-inclination) by William Shunn

> Jude Plane is a teenage boy who lives in a cloistered religious
> enclave on a giant space station. Jude's faith forbids him from using
> advanced technology, but that resolve is put to the test when his
> father sends him to work outside the enclave [*among the "sculpted"*] unloading freight at the
> station's hub. There Jude makes friends stranger than any he's known,
> and finds himself confronted by choices he couldn't have imagined just
> days earlier, including whether to embrace his new life or his old.

You can read a full version of the story online [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141029134057/http://will.tip.dhappy.org/blog/Compression%20Trees/.../book/by/William%20Shunn/Inclination/William%20Shunn%20-%20Inclination.html)

Comment: Not a full version - it stops halfway through.

Comment: @Ian - Fixed. Sorted.

Comment: @peregrineRook - I'd advise you to undelete your answer. Even though it didn't contain the right answer, it did have lots of highly relevant detail and is worthy of upvoting for being "useful", especially to future searchers.